# Display a picture on opening a new tab on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am a beginner to Chrome extension development and I am trying to create an extension which displays a random comic every time I open a new tab. (I don't have to randomise the picture. The link automatically provides a random image)

The following are my files,

**newtab.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="newtab.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**newtab.js**

```
var ImageSource = 'http://explosm.net/comics/random',
parser = new DOMParser();

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", ImageSource, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 )
    {
        var xml = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, 'text/xml'),
            imageUrl = getValueForElementNode(xml, 'img');

        document.write('<div><img src="'+imageUrl+'"></div>');
        setTimeout(function() { notify.close(); }, 4000);
    }
}
xhr.send();
});

function getValueForElementNode(doc, node) {
return doc.getElementsByTagName(node)[7].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Comic of the tab",
"description": "Delivers random comic strip from your favourite series!",
"version": "1.0.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"},
"chrome_url_overrides" : { "newtab": "newtab.html"},
"permissions" : [
                "clipboardWrite",
                "webRequest",
                "http://*",
                "http://explosm.net/"
            ],
"background": {
        "scripts": ["newtab.js"]
}
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

- VM472 extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler
  for tabs.onCreated: TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of
  undefined
     at getValueForElementNode (chrome-extension://pnhbnidjljkmhmnomejbfniemnpembea/newtab.js:17:45)
     at chrome-extension://pnhbnidjljkmhmnomejbfniemnpembea/newtab.js:9:28
- XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://explosm.net/comics/random. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://pnhbnidjljkmhmnomejbfniemnpembea' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Your being subject to the Same Origin Policy in chrome, which basically means that you are not allowed to request pages from origins (read "websites") which are not your own. This applies even in Chrome Extensions, however there is a way to surpass this. Modify your `manifest.json` like so:

```
"permissions": [
   "http://explosm.net/"
]
```

This will allow you to make requests to http://explosm.net (and also notify the user upon installation)

In addition, you must specify the pages you are going to override in your `manifest.json`, like so:

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
  "newtab": "mytab.html"
}
```

Then write your script pulling in the comic from explosm and displaying it on the page

Comment: If you want to create a new window, you can just `window.open`

Comment: No, I do not want to create a new window. I'd like the comic to be displayed on the new tab screen every time we open a new tab.

Comment: Isn't there an chrome API having to new tab pages. I haven't worked with it in a while, but I remember that being an extension type

Comment: @Bharg your cross origin permissions are too broad, and chrome is rejecting them, which is (I think) why you're getting errors

Comment: Yes, it is override page that I have used in my manifest.json already.I think the problem is with the xhr part where I need to find a different way to do document.write('<div><img src="'+imageUrl+'"></div>');

Comment: @Bharg Like I said, you must specify **exactly** http://explosm.net, or chrome will reject it